# How do I write entitlements to use NSWorkSpace's showSearchResultsForQueryString in sandboxed app?

Tags: cocoa, sandbox

I have made one sandboxed app which calls `NSWorkspace`'s `showSearchResultsForQueryString` but this method doesn't work.
I guess this error can be associated with entitlement key, but i could't find answer.
How can I implement entitlement key for this?

Answer (score 1):

That method won't work for a sandboxed app. It sends an Apple event to the Finder.

Have a look at this link in the sandbox design guide:

[Determine Whether Your App Is Suitable for Sandboxing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html)

and you'll see the following text:

> *With App Sandbox, you can receive Apple events and respond to Apple events, but you cannot send Apple events to arbitrary apps.*

Comment: Thanks, but to speak frankly, I could make this method worked at sandboxed application. If I edit entitlement file like this, method works.  <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
 <array>
  <string>com.apple.finder</string>
 </array> but this was rejected from apple ;(

Comment: A temporary exemption isn't an entitlement, it's an exemption from entitlements, and Apple are unlikely to grant you one unless you can convince them it's necessary and even then, only temporarily...

Comment: Yes, Really apple doesn't like that application to send apple event to other applications. But I have approved another sandboxed application which send apple event to safari and chrome using "com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events".It is really confused.

Answer (score 0):

This method can not be used in sandboxed application.
Because this method should be fixed to run within sandboxed application in future.